# android-- upload file to server but unable to save the file on server

Tags: java, php, android, apache, ubuntu

Hi so I managed to send file from app to server however it will return 503 (file not exist) after i send to server. can anyone check my code please

Error: HTTP Response is: Service Temporarily Unavailable: 503
I should get 502 if file exist or 200 OK if file uploaded

This is the java function.

```
private int upload(String uri_)
{
    String fileName = uri_;

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;  
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 
    File sourceFile = new File(uri_); 

    if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

        dialog.dismiss(); 

        Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :"
                            +fileName);


        return 0;

   }

    else
    {
         try { 

               // open a URL connection to the Servlet
             FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
             URL url = new URL(url_);

             // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
             conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

             // Allow Inputs & Outputs
             conn.setDoInput(true);
             conn.setDoOutput(true);
             conn.setUseCaches(false);

             // Enable POST method
             conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

             conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
             conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary");

             dos = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream() );
             dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
             dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + fileName );
             dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

             bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
             bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
             buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

             // read file and write it into form...
             bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

             while (bytesRead > 0) {

               dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
               bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
               bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
               bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);   

              }

             // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
             dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
             dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

             // Responses from the server (code and message)
             serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

             String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

             Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                     + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);
             if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                      public void run() {


                          Toast.makeText(PhotoActivity.this, "File Upload Complete.", 
                                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      }
                  });                
             }    

             //close the streams //
             fileInputStream.close();
             dos.flush();
             dos.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

            dialog.dismiss();  
            ex.printStackTrace();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    Toast.makeText(PhotoActivity.this, "MalformedURLException", 
                                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);  
        }
         catch (Exception e) {

             dialog.dismiss();  
             e.printStackTrace();

             runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                 public void run() {

                     Toast.makeText(PhotoActivity.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ", 
                             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }
             });
             Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : "
                                              + e.getMessage(), e);  
         }
         dialog.dismiss();       
         return serverResponseCode; 

      } // End else block 

}
```

for PHP part

```
<?php
$tar="./";
$src=$_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'];
$tar=$tar . basename($src);
if(file_exists($src))
{
if(move_uploaded_file($src,$tar))
{
echo "success";
}
else
{header("Server Error",ture,502);}
}
else
{header("Server Error",ture,503);}
?>
```

Comment: please be clear about your question.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/de/function.header.php header must return a boolean not a `ture` :) And do not close your php script just remove `?>`

Comment: i want to upload an image from phone storage to server but it never uploaded. I used header to track file statment, it seems like php doesnt recognize my image file . the problem is did i do anything wrong so the server can't receive my image from android app!?

Comment: Hi A.S. I followed your suggestion it doesnt work still :(

Answer (score 0):

Check if this could help you for your problem

http://lakjeewa.blogspot.in/2012/03/simple-android-application-to-send-file.html

Answer (score 0):

User this code in android applciation

```
package com.example.imageuploaddemo;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class UploadToServer extends Activity {

TextView messageText;
Button uploadButton;
int serverResponseCode = 0;
ProgressDialog dialog = null;
String upLoadServerUri = null;
/********** File Path *************/
final String uploadFilePath = "/mnt/sdcard/";
final String uploadFileName = "demo.pdf";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload_to_server);

    uploadButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.uploadButton);
    messageText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.messageText);

    messageText.setText("Uploading file path :- '/mnt/sdcard/"
            + uploadFileName + "'");

    /************* Php script path ****************/
    upLoadServerUri = "http://exampleserver/fileuploading.php";//php file path for used to save file

    uploadButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(UploadToServer.this, "",
                    "Uploading file...", true);

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            messageText.setText("uploading started.....");
                        }
                    });

                    uploadFile(uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);

                }
            }).start();
        }
    });
}

public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {

    String fileName = sourceFileUri;
    Log.e("Filena", ""+fileName);
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);
    Log.e("sourceFile", ""+sourceFile.getParent());
    if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

        dialog.dismiss();

        Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :" + uploadFilePath + ""
                + uploadFileName);

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                messageText.setText("Source File not exist :"
                        + uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);
            }
        });

        return 0;

    } else {
        try {

            // open a URL connection to the Servlet
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(
                    sourceFile);
            URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

            // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
            conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);

            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

            // dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploaded_file";filename=""
            // + fileName + """ + lineEnd);

            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\";filename=\""
                    + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            // create a buffer of maximum size
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // read file and write it into form...
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {

                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            }

            // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

            Log.e("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                    + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

            if (serverResponseCode == 200) {

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
                                + " http://www.example.com/uploads/"
                                + uploadFileName;

                        messageText.setText(msg);
                        Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this,
                                "File Upload Complete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                    }
                });
            }

            // close the streams //
            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

            dialog.dismiss();
            ex.printStackTrace();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    messageText
                            .setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                    Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this,
                            "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            });

            Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            dialog.dismiss();
            e.printStackTrace();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                    Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this,
                            "Got Exception : see logcat ",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            Log.e("Upload file to server Exception",
                    "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        dialog.dismiss();
        return serverResponseCode;

    } // End else block
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, but I added this permission to my php script which solved it for me.

```
chmod($YOUR_TARGET_PATH, 0777);
```

So try this...

```
<?php
$tar="./";

chmod($tar, 0777);

$src=$_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'];
$tar=$tar . basename($src);
if(file_exists($src))
{
if(move_uploaded_file($src,$tar))
{
echo "success";
}
else
{header("Server Error",ture,502);}
}
else
{header("Server Error",ture,503);}
?>
```